# How to use generic types for a function that merges two generic type objects?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to add a hook that takes `defaultParams` which is an object and returns a function that takes `allParams` and returns a merged object where the values are picked from `defaultParams` if they are `null` or `undefined` in `allParams`.

It's working as expected but I'm trying to improve the types of the final values. As commented in the below snippet the types of `page` and `count` are not accurate.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-x5TggA)

```
interface Person {
    firstName?: string
    count?: number
    pet?: boolean
}

type RequiredPick<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Required<Pick<T, K>>

const useDefaultParams = <T, DKey extends keyof T = keyof T>(defaultParams: { [K in DKey]?: NonNullable<T[K]> }) => {
    return (allParams: T) => {
        const allParamsWithDefaults = { ...allParams } as Partial<T>

        Object.entries(defaultParams).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            (allParamsWithDefaults as any)[key] ??= value!
        })
        return allParamsWithDefaults as RequiredPick<T, DKey>
    }
}

const defaultParams = { count: 10 }

const { count, pet, firstName } = useDefaultParams<Person>(defaultParams)({ firstName: 'firstName' })
// typeof pet should be undefined
// typeof count should be number
// typeof firstName should be string
```

Comment: `pet` should be `number | undefined`? But in your `Person` interface it's a `boolean`... Also, what should the type of `name` be?

Comment: Looks like you need currying as partial type inference is not supported? https://tsplay.dev/w6xaym

Comment: I'm not sure why you care about your `T` type; wouldn't [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WP1dkw) be just as good?  If not, can you articulate why you want the returned value to have any knowledge of `pet` at all since neither the default nor the subsequent value have a `pet` field?

Comment: @jcalz makes sense `pet` can be `undefined` as it is not passed in either of the objects, updated the question. I'm also trying to avoid using `object` and `any` types.

Comment: • Why are you trying to avoid `object`? That's a weird requirement.  • Feel free to change `any` to `unknown` in the constraint, but I put an `any` in `(allParamsWithDefaults as any)[key] ??= value!` because otherwise there's an error... if you don't want that, could you please clear up the error so there's no unrelated errors in your example code? • I'm still not sure why it matters that it's `Person` as opposed to any other type.  Lots of properties were not passed in, like `pet`, `hairColor`, `shoeSize, etc`; why shouldn't they just be unknown props instead of explicitly `undefined`?

Comment: ... but if you really do want to specify `Person` at the outset then you'll need to do something like @vr. showed with currying or some other workaround for the lack of partial type argument inference as per [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Does @vr.'s solution work for you? If so I'll bow out and let them write an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. I want to be able to pass an interface/type (`T`) when using the hook so that I get autocomplete and default params can only be a subset of all params. Also, I'm not sure what would be the right fix for the error in `allParamsWithDefaults)[key]` .

Comment: @jcalz updated the playground and question to fix that error

Comment: If currying is okay then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wRBMxw) is what I'd do, but I don't want to step on @vr.'s toes since it's not significantly different.  If currying is not okay then you need to relax at least one of your requirements or it's not possible.

Comment: @jcalz Got it. Post it as an answer. Can you explain this part `<U extends Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K> & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>>`?

Comment: I might write up an answer but I'd rather give @vr. a chance to do so first, since their approach is essentially the same.  I'll check back later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without support for partial type inference as proposed in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), you would have to curry `useDefaultParams` to allow TS to perform inference on the original second type parameter:

```
const useDefaultParams = <T>() => {
    return <DKey extends keyof T>(defaultParams: {
        [K in DKey]?: NonNullable<T[K]>;
    }) => {
        return (allParams: T) => {
            const allParamsWithDefaults = { ...allParams } as Partial<T>;

            Object.entries(defaultParams).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                //@ts-ignore
                allParamsWithDefaults[key] ??= value!;
            });

            return allParamsWithDefaults as RequiredPick<T, DKey>;
        };
    };
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAPwBcyGYUoA5gNxEkJYCu4tp3cgCNo7EsgAOEMPyFYsAGwhwQ7AL4ECYAJ5TkAJQgBHbsCgQAJqmAIA1gB4AKgBpkAaWQQAHpBAWMyLYQ2lgwyI4AfMgAvMgA8uTAYE6ublEAZAbGpuYW9tZ2Ke4REewEXCAMyNwYEAAiEPDcCmCocFAUAbFOEQAUAJQxUYTi5mDcULj2dW7Bnj4QfgFBIWGRvRaNcM2t7Z10I+IkANoeoMgzwQC6-AByOLfNCnBCSk6nV6UcxGqD0cPfI5jCa4XpwBQKNodcgYOiOP4Ao5I5AVKrgyF7GEAdSSAAsGk0Wl18MgAHTk9FQzrINTIOABKFgYDgnplZFHOJCABWEAQYFJi0YwAgGA2Wx2VJh-VJMCwUAAoohcb1escVq4AG7g7gQK4I-CA9niAD0xoAAmAMABaYDMEByiCGo3ESmYjA4sD48VEtXXZBUKixLUKHUAQjEzpp-TZkeBkzpEMl7rxBO2RLpAUMJjMlgKDhcF1m2i+7LUEZ+6jKqLAyE2hN20OJeBRPHAdAAjAAGGlVnBVZtcXhgVxSGu02I1erehudfKYHB9fpi+tJpeHYhkSh0ABEm4g2+cBF+7CAA)

---

With [jcalz's version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75837648/how-to-use-generic-types-for-a-function-that-merges-two-generic-type-objects#comment133772464_75837648), it's the same idea, but with a little extra magic. The use of `Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K> & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>` is to make sure you don't pass in a parameter already given by `defaultParams`, and the mapped type on the return value creates a new type from `defaultParams` and `allParams`.

```
{
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K
        ? T[K]
        : P extends keyof U
        ? U[P]
        : never;
}
```